# Recommendations without ratings (Azure ML)

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to build an experiment to create recommendations (using the Movie Ratings sample database), but without using the ratings. I simply consider that if a user has rated certain movies, then he would be interested by other movies that have been rated by users that have also rated his movies.

I can consider, for instance, that ratings are 1 (exists in the database) or 0 (does not exist), but in that case, how do I transform the initial data to reflect this?

I couldn't find any kind of examples or tutorials about this kind of scenario, and I don't really know how to proceed. Should I transform the data before injecting it into an algorithm? And/or is there any kind of specific algorithm that I should use?

Comment: What do you mean by 'transform the initial data'? A binary representation of the ratings - such as the one that you are suggesting - is enough (an a good one) for a simple experiment. From there you could just look into a simple implementation of collaborative filtering.

Comment: My confusion has more to do with how I can associate a value with data that isn't there, since all ratings will be "1" in the database, as the only way to have a rating of "0" is for it not to be present in the data...

Comment: You could store the values in a sparse matrix (users X movies). That way you don't need to represent the 0's

Comment: Is it possible to convert to a sparse matrix within Azure ML Studio itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hoping to use the Matchbox Recommender in AML, you're correct that you need to identify some user-movie pairs that *are* not present in the raw dataset, and add these in with a rating of zero. (I'll assume that you have already set all of the real user-movie pairs to have a rating of one, as you described above.)

I would recommend generating some random candidate pairs and confirming their absence from the training data in an Execute R (or Python) Script module. I don't know the names of your dataset's features, but here is some pseudocode in R to do that:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- maml.mapInputPort(1)  # input dataset of observed user-movie pairs
all_movies <- unique(df[['movie']])
all_users <- unique(df[['user']])
n <- 30  # number of random pairs to start with

negative_observations <- data.frame(movie = sample(all_movies, n, replace=TRUE),
                                    user = sample(all_users, n, replace=TRUE),
                                    rating = rep(0, n))          
acceptable_negative_observations <- anti_join(unique(negative_observations), df, by=c('movie', 'user'))
df <- rbind(df, acceptable_negative_observations)
maml.mapOutputPort("df");
```

Alternatively, you could try a method like [association rule learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) which would not require you to add in the fake zero ratings. Martin Machac has posted a [nice example](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Frequently-bought-together-market-basket-analyses-using-ARULES-1) of how to do this in R/AML in the Cortana Intelligence Gallery.

Comment: But, what is default behavior, if the data does not exists for all combinations? Just fixed rating=1 by Azure ML , and that is it.., nothing to calculate and add to row dataset (with rating=0)